# insert query not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an update query that works when run in isolation, but complains when called inside a stored procedure.

```
mysql> UPDATE `user` SET `password`=COALESCE(NULL, `password`) WHERE `id`=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> CALL updateUser(1, NULL, NULL, '1950-02-05', NULL);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'male' cannot be null
```

Here's the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateUser` (IN userId varchar(255), IN password varchar(100), IN male tinyint(1), IN birthday datetime, IN fbId varchar(160))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE `user` SET `male` = IFNULL(male, `male`), `password` = IFNULL(password, `password`), `birthday` = IFNULL(birthday, `birthday`) WHERE `id` = userId;

        IF fbId IS NOT NULL THEN
            ...
        END IF;
    COMMIT;
END
```

I have also tried defining the update query using COALESCE instead of IFNULL, but the results were the same. Does anyone have an idea about what's going on and how could I get my procedure working?

Comment: I'm not sure how it will behave when your input params have the same names as their destination columns. Try renaming the parameters to `in_male, in_password`, etc in the procedure to disambiguate them from the column names.

Comment: Backticks are used to quote _identifiers_, and parameters are identifiers. Since parameters resolve with higher prio than table columns, it'll be running `SET male = IFNULL(NULL,NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stored procedure arguments are the same as the names of the columns.  Try this instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateUser` (IN p_userId varchar(255),
                               IN p_password varchar(100),
                               IN p_male tinyint(1),
                               IN p_birthday datetime,
                               IN p_fbId varchar(160))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
        UPDATE `user` SET `male` = IFNULL(p_male, `male`),
                          `password` = IFNULL(p_password, `password`),
                          `birthday` = IFNULL(p_birthday, `birthday`)
        WHERE `id` = p_userId;

        IF fbId IS NOT NULL THEN
            ...
        END IF;
    COMMIT;
END
```

You are getting the error about `male` not accepting NULL values because the expression:

```
coalesce(male, `male`)
```

Is referring both times to the stored procedure argument rather than the column in the table.